# How to get id for each Object keys

Tags: javascript, object, key

l have following data json ,  Contain on Object keys and those keys are change regular

```
  "2461ba4c": [ // <----------- get the main key for each one 
    "4BD436",
    36.346,
    33.478,
  ],
  "2461b87c": [
    "06A128",
    34.628,
    33.584,

  ]
```

I would like to get the keys of object for each an array .

I did filter for keys `.filter(key => key )` but it gave me all keys of objects . I want to each array the main keys objects .

```
function data() {
  $.ajax('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 5000
  }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    Object.keys(data)
      .map(key => data[key])
      .map((position) => ({
        lat: position[1],
        lng: position[2],
                        // <----------- Add the main key here for each array
      })).filter(position => position.lat && position.lng).forEach(i => {
        console.log(i.lat, i.lng, i.heading)
      })
  })
}
```

expected output :

```
2461b87c, // <---main key
34.628,
33.584,
```

Comment: Do you need like this? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/MWajjwE (Look at console)

Comment: a little bit . l want add the main key under `.map((position) => ({
                lat: position[1],
                lng: position[2],

        }))`

Comment: I made a snippet. What is expected output?

Comment: @AliGhassan, Can you post your expected output as well??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan check out please

Comment: @AliGhassan, I have made an answer, can you check it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new obj inside map method and assign the key value like,

```
const dataObj = {
    lat: position[1],
    lng: position[2],
    heading: key
  }
```

and return the object.

The **snippet** as follows,

```js
const data = {
  "2461ba4c": [
    "4BD436",
    36.346,
    33.478,
  ],
  "2461b87c": [
    "06A128",
    34.628,
    33.584,

  ]
}

const newData = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
  const position = data[key];
  const dataObj = {
    lat: position[1],
    lng: position[2],
    heading: key
  }
  return dataObj;
})

newData.filter(position => position.lat && position.lng).forEach(i => {
    console.log(i.lat, i.lng, i.heading)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `in` loop for this

```js
let arr =  {"2461ba4c": [ 
    "4BD436",
    36.346,
    33.478,
  ],
  "2461b87c": [
    "06A128",
    34.628,
    33.584,
  ]};
  
for( let a in arr){
  document.write(a+"<br>"); 
}
```

Comment: the first answer is  worked for me . thank you for trying to help me